# Getting an error when implementing react navigation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

```
// In APP.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Nave() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
----------------------------------------------------------
In package.json

"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.14",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elz9M.png)

If I could get some help, it wouldn't be a denial.
I already did a complete re-installation via npm of react-native and react-navigation following the documentation.
But, I don't understand why my app doesn't launch and displays this error message. Knowing that I use an ios simulator on Macos catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `@react-navigation/native` in your `package.json`. Did you follow the instructions in the [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)?

First run:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

Then run:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Then you should be able to follow their [Hello React Native tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/).